# iOS app restriction for specific devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, iphone-5

I want my iOS app to run on iPhone 5 or later devices.

I have also tried ARMv7s via info plist. Its not working for me.

My app can't build for only for iPhone 5.

How can I restrict my app only for iPhone 5, iPhone 5s or later devices?

Because I have visited many other questions on stackoverflow, mostly asking for ios limit. Thats is not proper solution for my app. That's Why this thread created to discuss various options.

Please help me

Comment: did you tried setting deployment target to 5.0 or 5.1 ?

Comment: @exculuber That's not iPhone version, but iOS version.

Comment: @exculuber as already been said that is iOS version not iPhone version so will not help. `@M.Irfan`Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191657/restrict-to-certain-ios-target-devices-for-app-store-submission I'm not sure it is possible to restrict device. Though I am not 100% I would do a little bit more research, please note that all I did was drop you title into google and I found a few answers. Always google your title before asking the question.