# Exclude devices that use 1x in assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, app-store

I basically want to exclude iPhone 4 and support from iPhone 5 or newer so I've found this little article stating that it is possible and Apple is officially allowing it.
http://www.itworld.com/article/2934373/with-ios-9-developers-will-be-able-to-limit-their-apps-to-newer-devices.html

But then I cannot find anything on how exactly. The article does mention something about plist but not much at all.

Also, they suggest that this method will allow iPhone 5s or newer but I'd like to add iPhone 5 as well just before 5s.

Any idea..?

**EDIT**
Just realized iPhone 4 uses 2x.... why hasn't anyone commented on that..?
This should be closed.

Comment: Why exclude iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S?

Comment: Since the iPhone 5 and 4S are not that different I suggest you set the deployment target to iOS 8. This will exclude iPhone 4, but not the iPhone 4S.

Comment: @Larme I think I'll now end up including all devices.. but I really wanted to take off the huge burden of having to design for 1x and other related stuffs that come with it such as re-positioning according to such small screen etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You also can add some option to info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and add supporting only arm64 please look [doccumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Comment: Yeah I already know about that one but this answer on SO suggests not to because that method got their apps rejected. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16257987/5184188

Comment: please look a comment in this post "I agree. I also had an app rejected by Apple because of required capabilities in the plist which were not used in the app. Either you use the features required in the plist, or you must remove them from the requirements. Adding a requirement to the plist simply to restrict the hardware will lead your app to be rejected"

Comment: But then what's the point...? So you're suggesting me to add whatever feature I can find and apply to "fix" the problem I have but this only sounds like I'll be adding more problem plus work plus time plus so many other unnecessary things. Obviously better to just include iPhone 4 and be done if I had to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: I think you simply need delete LaunchImage for 3.5 inch