# How to restrict my app to iphone 5s and above?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, healthkit

I am using healthkit in my application to read user's steps. But unfortunately iphone 5 and below does not have M7 sensor due to which my app can not perfome its full functionalities on those devices. So is there any possible way that user having iphone 5 or below could not install my app from app store ? Or any other possible workout/behaviour suggested ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191657/restrict-to-certain-ios-target-devices-for-app-store-submission Duplicate

Comment: My question also include any possible work around for this case ?

Comment: Everything is provided in that, even if any work around exists.

Comment: I have asked for suggestions in this particular case (Healthkit). I have seen that link that does not help.

Comment: I don't think so you can't force app store to restrict device to certain device type. You can check whether the device has M7 sensor, through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869659/detecting-if-a-user-is-moving-in-a-car. And provide a alert to the user that his phone requires M7 sensor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the HealthKit key of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your .plist file.

Documentation on UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities.

The healthkit bit says:

> **healthkit** Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) HealthKit.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you can't restrict application to device specific.

> All device requirement changes must be made when you submit an update
>   to your binary. You are permitted only to expand your device
>   requirements. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your
>   device requirements is not permitted. You are unable to restrict
>   device requirements because this action will keep customers who have
>   previously downloaded your app from running new updates.

don't know any work around regarding `Healthkit`, still if any may result in app rejection.

> The value of the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key is either an array
>   or a dictionary that contains additional keys identifying features
>   your app requires (or specifically prohibits).
>
> Be sure to include keys only for the features that your app absolutely
>   requires. If your app can run without a specific feature, do not
>   include the corresponding key.

Can read more details in docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html