# Is there a way to restrict my app to iPhone X and above? Or 8 and above?

Tags: ios, iphone, device-compatibility

I would like my app to be used on iPhone8 or above only. I've checked [iOS Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) but i believe it's outdated. No mention of the newer phones like XS/XS Max/XR.

iPhone8/X & above use the A11 Bionic chips, Water resistant to a depth of 1 metre for up to 30 minutes & supports Wireless charging or even devices with **the notch**. Features not available in older devices/models.

I have already restricted it to iPhone7 & above by using *nfc* as `key` in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`

So is there a way to restrict my app to iPhone 8/X and above by setting the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` keys? If so what are those `keys`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict to certain iOS target devices for App Store submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191657/restrict-to-certain-ios-target-devices-for-app-store-submission)

Comment: @TheNeil I did read the link you mentioned before asking this question. But my question is for specific device. iPhone8/X & above(newer models). Not regarding the number of cores in their processor.

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you want such a restriction. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: @rmaddy My app works better with the `UIWhitePointAdaptivityStyle` compatible devices.

Comment: Hello @Ajo You can also check screen size and set message to user

Comment: @DhavalUmraliya I'm sorry can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ajo https://github.com/avdyushin/SwiftDevice try

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

An alternative could be checking the device on AppDelegate didFinishLaunching and prompting a device not supported then close app

Comment: But that's a really bad UX. Isn't it?